# Symfony2 Field Type Guessing: When is <textarea> chosen (over <input type="text">)?

Tags: forms, symfony

Not declaring the field type brings the advantage that Symfony infers the `required` and `maxlength` attribute from validation rules, as explained here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#field-type-options-guessing

However, I can't find a way to make Symfony 2.8.2 "guess" a `<textarea>` instead of an `<input type="text">` :-(

My first idea was to increase the allowed length, but even with `Length: max: 100000` in validation.yml, Symfony is unimpressed and just gives me `<input type="text" maxlength="100000" />`.

EDIT: @chalasr: I'm talking about an entity which is **not** mapped to the database. Sorry for not mentioning that earlier!

Comment: I just opened an issue for this: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/36521

Answer (score 4):

The `FormBuilder` guesses the field type by checking the type in the mapping of the corresponding property, in the entity.

Use `text` instead of `string` as `type` of your column mapping, and the `FormBuilder` will use a textarea instead of an input.

Example :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text")
 */
protected $field;
```

Output with `$builder->add('field');` :

```
<textarea id="entity_field" name="entity[field]" required="required"></textarea>
```

For more info look at the [Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\DoctrineOrmTypeGuesser](https://github.com/symfony/doctrine-bridge/blob/master/Form/DoctrineOrmTypeGuesser.php).

**Update**

So, you don't use a mapped class.

Look at the [`FormBuilder`](https://github.com/symfony/form/blob/master/FormFactory.php#L100), as you can see, if there is no corresponding `Guesser` found, the form type will be a `TextType` (input text).

Otherwise, there is 3 different `Guesser`:

- [`FormTypeGuesserChain`](https://github.com/symfony/form/blob/master/FormTypeGuesserChain.php)
- [`DoctrineORMTypeGuesser`](https://github.com/symfony/doctrine-bridge/blob/master/Form/DoctrineOrmTypeGuesser.php)
- [`ValidatorTypeGuesser`](https://github.com/symfony/form/blob/master/Extension/Validator/ValidatorTypeGuesser.php)

Because your class is not mapped, Symfony will use the `ValidatorTypeGuesser` to guess the type of your field.

This `Guesser` looks for constraints in your class.
For example, if your field has a `Type` constraint with type `integer`, the `NumberType` will be used and an input type `number` will be rendered.

My first idea was to use a `Length` constraint with a big min-length.

But, after many tries and looks in classes, it seems the `TextareaType` is never guessed, unless your class is mapped and your field has `text` as type (`DoctrineTypeGuesser` is used) .

So, without a mapped class, Symfony cannot create a `textarea` from type guessing.

For more informations look at the [`ValidatorTypeGuesser::guessTypeForConstraint`](https://github.com/symfony/form/blob/master/Extension/Validator/ValidatorTypeGuesser.php#L80).

See also the [Form Type Guessing](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/type_guesser.html#guessing-the-type) chapter of documentation, it shows how create your own `TypeGuesser` with a good example.